# Curl is Fetching different data than expectation from aspx site

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am trying to fetch data from [here](http://164.100.153.3/e-registration/booth_entry_report.aspx) and for that I used the following code. But it is giving different result from as we can find in browser. I do not know why is this happening. Please help me. Also there is no content inside log file and cookie file.
My code:

```
<?php
function curl($url ,$binary=false,$post=false,$cookie =false ){
    touch($cookie);

$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



        if($cookie){

            $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

        }


        if($binary)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

        if($post){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        }

     return  curl_exec ($ch);
     echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
}
$dist=01; 
$assem=98;
$ok="Proceed";
$url="http://164.100.153.3/e-registration/booth_entry_report.aspx"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
touch($cookie);
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36';


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

$postdata = "ddldistrict=".$dist."&ddlassembly=".$assem."&btnproceed=".$ok."&VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate."&EVENTVALIDATION".$eventValidation; 

// function
$ch = curl($url,false,$postdata,$cookie);
//$url ='http://164.100.153.3/e-registration/booth_level_officer_report.aspx';
//$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

//$ch =curl($url,false,false,$cookie);

echo $ch;
?>
```

Real result from browser:
[image]
difeerent rresult which curl returns:
[image]

Comment: I had edited the question please see it, how is the result differs.

Comment: updated my answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are crawling needs more POST arguments (Firebug tells me). That form has '__VIEWSTATE' and '__EVENTVALIDATION' POSTed too (and some more, so just check that too).

Additionally, the form is submitted to the same page, "booth_entry_report.aspx", then it gets REDIRECTED (code 302) to the "booth_level_officer_report.aspx" page. So you dont need the 2nd curl() becuase 1st one already has the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.

Also, there may be some issue with the sent headers. I suggest you get Firebug, or better Fiddler to see the requests sent by the browser, and compare that with the info sent with php curl.

To see what headers php curl sends, call curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true) , then echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) after curl_exec().

**UPDATE:**
Make sure the '__' is before those post params.

Set the ddldistrict and ddlassembly to be strings ('01' and '98')

I suggest you go throuhg all the pageloads that page does:

1. GET the page and read the '__' params
2. Set the referer and POST to the same page with all the '_' params + the ddldistrict='01' and read the'__' params again
3. Set the referer and POST to the same page again with those params + ddldistrict='01' + ddlassembly='98' + btnproceed='Proceed'

**UPDATE 2 with code:**
Below is what I say above, with code. But I am afraid I can not help you further then this. That page does seem tricky. Good luck!

```
$dist='01'; 
$assem='98';
$ok="Proceed";
$url="http://164.100.153.3/e-registration/booth_entry_report.aspx"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt";

/////// get the first page
$ch = curl_init($url);
// here curl_setopt() for url, cookie, useragent, followlocation, etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// get those variables with preg_match
preg_match('... __VIEWSTATE ...', $html, $viewstate);
$viewstate = $viewstate[1];

preg_match('... __EVENTVALIDATION ...', $html, $eventValidation);
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

// do the preg_match for '__EVENTTARGET', '__EVENTARGUMENT', '__LASTFOCUS'


//////// do the next request
// the first post data with 'dllassembly=0' and without 'btnprocess'. Like when you selected the "District name" in the browser.
$postdata = "ddldistrict=".$dist."&ddlassembly=0&__VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate."&__EVENTVALIDATION".$eventValidation // add the rest of the __ fields too

// post it with referer
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); // this with referer
// here curl_setopt() for post data, url, cookie, useragent, followlocation, etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// here get all the '__' fields again with preg_match(), just like last time
preg_match('... __VIEWSTATE ...', $html, $viewstate);
$viewstate = $viewstate[1];

preg_match('... __EVENTVALIDATION ...', $html, $eventValidation);
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];

// do the preg_match for '__EVENTTARGET', '__EVENTARGUMENT', '__LASTFOCUS'


//////// do the last request
// the second post data with 'dllassembly=98' and also 'btnprocess'. Like when you clicked "Procees" in the browser.
$postdata = "ddldistrict=".$dist."&ddlassembly=".$assem."&btnproceed=".$ok."&__VIEWSTATE=".$viewstate."&__EVENTVALIDATION".$eventValidation // add the rest of the __ fields too

// and finally post it with referer
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); // this with referer
// here curl_setopt() for post data, url, cookie, useragent, followlocation, etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And note on the post param creation. A better was is to make an associative array, and use http_build_query(). Like this

```
$post_data = array(
    'ddldistrict' => '01',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventValidation,
    '....' => '....'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```

Comment: Hello, please, I had edited above code in question, please review it, it is still not getting any data.

Comment: Thanks @Skacc, this is really awesome, it's working fine. Thanks again and also without http_build_query, it's working. But thanks for giving your time and knowledge.